# Lazy loading or on demand

Tags: javascript, lazy-evaluation, lazy-loading, ondemand

This is my web: http://www.alvaromillan.es.
I've proved almost everything but the loading is still taking too long... I think the problem could be the javascript which load all the images... I'd like this javascript to be loaded just when the user clicks on a thumbnail (this javascript is a lightbox) but I don´t know how to do it. I've read about lazy load and on demand but I couldn't get it... But I'd like to do the lazy or on demand stuff... Could you please help me?

Now I have this code but this only says that this script is executed at the very end:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeslideshow.js">
    function downloadJSAtOnload(){
        var element=document.createElement("script");
        element.src="js/fadeslideshow.js";document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    if(window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load",downloadJSAtOnload,false);
    else if(window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload);
    else
        window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the script at the bottom of the html page, it will execute immediately, and be able to access everything on the page.

An alternative is to use `DOMContentLoaded` as opposed to `onload`, as the latter waits for all the images to load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="element">
            Howdy
        </div>


        <script>
            alert("That div says " + document.getElementById("element").innerHTML);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean I should change all the onLoad and put DOMContentLoaded ?

Comment: Yes, or just put the scripts at the bottom of the page; the script will run after the html has loaded and before images are done loading.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: You have referred to `onLoad`, which is not accurate (it should be `onload` - see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events#Simple_DOM.c2.a0events)). I have corrected it.